# Open external link in background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http, external-links

This is the question to webmasters. I'm looking for a tip, tool or direction.
Or maybe someone could give me the solution. The problem sounds simple.

I have my own http server which interpret and answer for http requests.

## Example:

If i enter link: http:// ip_server/link1 , it makes some functionality

---

If i enter link: http:// ip_server/link2 , it makes another funtionality
 ect.

## Problem:

What i want to do is to have another website on different domain with buttons. 
When user clicks button, it enters a link on my own server e.g. http:// ip_server/ link1
but the webiste with buttons will remain unchanged.

It's something like HTML href which opens link but doesn't open new website hide under this link. I was thinking about it and consider the problem that it could be impossible direct from webbrowser because, it is insecure and blocked by security.

From my point of view the only one solution will be PHP server or Java Servlet on which i can connect to my own serwer. Or there's a way to do it by ajax, jquery, js. Maybe i'm looking to far.

Comment: Not sure what the goal is. You want to open up a link to another site when a button is clicked, but not actually show the site?

Comment: you can not do like this...there is crossbrowser issue

Comment: "not actually show the site" well the site or answer for this link could be open in small part of this website or in another window

Answer (score 0):

you could simply "request" the Url with ajax, sth like this pseudoCode:

```
$('button').on("click",function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http:// ip_server/link1',
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(){
            console.log("success");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: And what about the cross domain problem?

Comment: You can not do like this

Comment: well you could use yahoo-query-language to solve that or you have your own proxy, a simple php file_get_contents should be enough

Comment: The bigest problem is to cross domain and connect to link in another domain, it does't have to be hide somthing behind this link can be opened in another window or in actual webstie but just in a small part